# Creating a new pandas dataframe column with one added value, then a copy of values from another column underneath it

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I'm currently trying to construct a new pandas dataframe, `interim_data_output` to copy raw data values into, in order to perform calculations on. My idea to do this is to have a subheading, Cycle number, and then all the values from another column in another dataframe, column `raw_data['CycleNumber']` after it.

My input column, `raw_data['CycleNumber']` looks like this:

```
print(raw_data['CycleNumber'])

0    1
1    1
2    1
3    1
4    1
5    1
6    1
7    1
Name: CycleNumber, dtype: int64
```

So I would start a new column, `interim_data_output['CN5']` , with an additional value at the start of the column, `*Cycle number'`, and then all the values from the raw data column `raw_data['CycleNumber']` following after this extra value.

My So my intended output would be:

```
print (interim_data_output['CN5'])

     CN5
0    *Cycle number
1    1
2    1
3    1
```

My original idea to get the desired output was to try this:

```
interim_data_output = pd.DataFrame()
interim_data_output['CN5'] = '*Cycle number', raw_data['CycleNumber']
```

This however doesn't work, as I merely get this:

```
print (interim_data_output['CN5'])

0                                        *Cycle number
1    0           1
1           1
2           1
3   ...
Name: CN5, dtype: object
```

I realise this is something very easy probably, but what am I missing here? Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Please provide a complete reproducible minimal example (input+output): [How to make good reproducible pandas examples](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20109391/how-to-make-good-reproducible-pandas-examples)

Comment: I have added my input, and shown the desired output and the current state of the output.

Answer (score 1):

`k=raw_data['CycleNumber'].tolist()     k.insert(0, '*Cycle number')     data_new={'CN5' : k}  interim_data_output=pd.DataFrame(data_new)`
Please ignore the formatting. this should work

Comment: Thanks, this works great! I really appreciate you taking the time to help.

Answer (score 0):

interim_data_output['CN5']=1
interim_data_output['CN5'].iloc[0]='*Cycle number'

Comment: Thanks, but that doesn't add the values from `raw_data['CycleNumber']` after, as that's part of my desired output?

Comment: Then use ```interim_data_output['CN5']=raw_data['CycleNumber']``` instead of the first line ?

Comment: @MurrayRoss use the solution mentioned above

Comment: Thanks, but that replaces the first value of `raw_data['CycleNumber']` when `interim_data_output['CN5'].iloc[0]='*Cycle number'` is performed?

Comment: `interim_data_output['CN5']=raw_data['CycleNumber']    interim_data_output['CN5'].iloc[0]='*Cycle number'`

Comment: Yes, but that replaces the first value of `raw_data['CycleNumber']` when you insert the `'*Cycle Number' ` at position 0 of the `interim_data_output`. I don't want to replace any values, I want to retain them all and merely place the `'*Cycle number'` before them.

Comment: i am not able understand what you mean, do you want to append the text  '*Cycle number' before each value ? like  `0 *Cycle number    1*Cycle number  `

Comment: No, I just want to append it before the first value, but the code provided replaces the first value, it does not append it before all the other values. So if my  `raw_data` had 50,000 values, then `interim_data_output` would have 50,001 - the value `*Cycle number` and all the values from the raw_data column.